# Как вывести значение переменной в span, расположеный на странице?

Tags: javascript, html

Нужно вывести значение переменной input в span, расположенный на странице.

```
<body>
    <div>Вы ввели: <span></span></div>

    <script>
        let input = prompt("Введите сообщение");
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<body>
    <div>Вы ввели: <span></span></div>

    <script>
        let input = prompt("Введите сообщение");
        const span = document.querySelector('span');
        span.textContent = input;
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let input = prompt("Введите сообщение");
document.querySelector('#test').textContent = input;
```

```html
<div>Вы ввели: <span id="test"></span></div>
```